# django locale is not loading correctly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, locale, chinese-locale

I am using django 1.8.7.

From my understanding django locale is supposed to be loading from 
`<site_root>/locale/<lang_code>/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

I have 
`<site_root>/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

and ran
`python3 manage.py compilemessages` and
 I got 
`<site_root>/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo` and 
I have
`request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = 'zh-cn'`

But my django application not loading anything from my `<site_root>/locale/zn_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` but only loading a few translations from locale translation from django 's default translations.

`django/contrib/auth/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

Somewhere should I look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my django settings for Persian language:

```
import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3  # (my_awesome_project/config/settings/base.py - 3 = my_awesome_project/)
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path('my_awesome_project')

###### Locale settings
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('locale')),
)

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    # Translators: This message appears on the home page only
    ('fa', gettext('Persian')),
)
```

And in my code I use it in this way:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

raise ValidationError(_("League dos'nt exist"))
```

Then in command line I run this command:

```
python manage.py makemessages
```

Then I edit `my_awesome_projec/my_awesome_projec/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` file according to Persian translation.

Then I run this command:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

and in production I add this directive to my nginx settings:

> proxy_pass_header "Accept-Language";

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I missed the `LOCALE_PATHS`  in settings.